# How can I show only the allocated resources in Docker container?

Tags: linux, memory, docker, cpu

Just a simple question I googled for a while but found no answer: How can I display only the allocated resources (cpu cores / memory) inside of a Docker container using top / htop and so on?

Kind regards and a nice weekend :)

~ Morph

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'docker stats' shows cpu/mem/net io usage.

https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/reference/commandline/stats/

'docker ps -s' shows size of containers.

[Docker - How to analyze a container's disk usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753087/docker-how-to-analyze-a-containers-disk-usage)

Memory and disk are shared between docker containers so you can expect to see memory and disk use inside a container to show shared resource size + individual container resource size.

Comment: Hi gaoithe and thanks for your response!
I know that it's possible to get the stats on the host, but is there a way to let the container show only the limited values in top / htop?

Comment: The container will just see all memory and disk, it mostly isn't aware it is a container. top will just show totals. Looking in /proc allows a certain amount of introspection in container. E.g. here http://tuhrig.de/how-to-know-you-are-inside-a-docker-container/

Comment: Hi again and thanks a lot! "it mostly isn't aware it is a container." << That was not clear to me until a moment ago. Thank you very much and have a nice weekend :)

~ Morph

Comment: This is very good description of the state of /proc and memory introspection on containers and a suggested standard solution. https://fabiokung.com/2014/03/13/memory-inside-linux-containers/

Comment: Really nice, thanks! :) I'll read everything I can get to learn more about Docker!