# Docker overlay2 disk usage

Tags: docker

I have a problem with overlay2 disk usage

When I executing df -h, I have 222G used disk space:

`Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/docker-docker   264G  222G   43G  85% /docker`

When I executing du -shc *, in /docker directory, I have 36G used disk space:

`17G     containers
14M     image
256K    network
19G     overlay2
0       plugins
0       swarm
0       tmp
0       trust
32K     volumes
36G     total`

Why such difference in used disk space?

PS if I restart docker, disk space freed up

PSS I don't have 'Exited' containers, and unused images/volume

Answer (score 3):

`du` command somehow counts space multiple times. I think it depends on fact that each docker directory is a separate mount.
For analyzing disk space you can use `docker system df` command.

Please read [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_df/) about.

Also, you can read this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753087/docker-how-to-analyze-a-containers-disk-usage) about analyzing disk space.

Comment: I already read this documentation and this discussion. docker system df did not show any relevant information.`

[user@localhost ~]$ sudo docker system df
TYPE                TOTAL               ACTIVE              SIZE                RECLAIMABLE
Images              37                  36                  6.428 GB            531.1 MB (8%)
Containers          69                  69                  2.582 MB            0 B (0%)
Local Volumes       2                   2                   0 B                 0 B
[user@localhost ~]$

`

Comment: And? ```du``` does not print correct information too.  When open issue?

Comment: And? Your answer is useless

Comment: My answer is useful. If you want to use this information. Read links more one time...

Comment: I can read your answer more and more times,  but that won't make it useful. Pls don't write in this topik. I already found the cause of the error.