# How can I tell the disk-size of an IOT-Edge module?

Tags: linux, azure, docker, diskspace, azure-iot-edge

On Azure I got an IoT Edge device with some modules (containers) installed in it (it's a Linux machine). Could not find anywhere how I can tell the disk size of those modules. The problem is that some of the modules are deployed remotely by some proprietary software, whose size I cannot know in advance.  Question is - how can I tell the size of each module?

Comment: If my answer helped solve your problem, then please accept/upvote it.  This helps others coming here with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IotEdge modules are docker containers so you can ssh on your machine and use

```
sudo docker ps --size
```

A broader discussion on disk usage of docker containers can be found here:
[How to analyze disk usage of a Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753087/how-to-analyze-disk-usage-of-a-docker-container)